# Installing ORDS in apex 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex

I am a beginner in apex, I wanted to install ORDS, so I followed the official documentation of the tool, except that when launching the page at the URL: 
http://localhost:8080/ords/

I encounter an error:
Unable to match the request with a database. Verify that the URL of the request is correct and that the URL-database matches have been configured correctly.

Infos:
APEX_Version: 5.1.2,
ORDS_Version: 3.0.11,
ORACLE_DB_Version: 11.2

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see steps you actually followed to comment - there is a configuration that happens for both apex and ords. check out my install tips [here](http://joestechland.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/installAPEX.txt) and make sure you followed them.

My script works every time. I find some of that site's instructions not needed. Also, what OS are you on?  Might be best to uninstall and delete the apex and ords dirs, reboot and start over with my script ;-)

Or, you could just download a free, pre-installed Virtual Box Image form oracle and avoid the hassle of installing the product yourself, [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html).